# JFrog artifactory docker image size trough REST

Tags: rest, docker, artifactory, docker-registry

After pushing image to JFrog artifactory docker registry, I want to get image size trough REST api, is there any API for this ?

Comment: Can you describe the use case? Why do you need it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Artifactory REST API to query many options in your Artifactory.
See [JFrog Artifactory REST API](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API) docs for all options.

Since a Docker image is saved as layers, you need to query the file list in the folder where the layers are and then sum all "size" parameters for each file.

List files (see "size"): [File list API](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-FileList)

I hope this helps.